# Is it possible to override the return of a controller method using a NestJS decorator?

Tags: controller, overriding, nestjs, decorator

I'd like to create an `@IgnoreDev` decorator that overrides a method return on a NestJS controller when it detects that we're running code in a dev environment.

For example:

```
@Controller()
class SomeController {

  @IgnoreDev
  async processMessage(...) {
    return 'processed';
  }
}
```

The `@IgnoreDev` annotation would detect that `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` and return `ignored` instead of `processed`;

Comment: I'd use [interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) for such task. And then just `@UseIntercetors(IgnoreOnDevInterceptor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with Mical Levi. You can use Interceptors for overriding the response from the controller.

Create a new file with the name **response.override.interceptor.ts**
Place the following code :

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class OverrideResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") return "ignored ";
        else return "processed";
      })
    );
  }
}
```

After creating the interceptor you just have to place the **@UseInterceptors()** decorator (imported from nestjs/common package ) over the controller and pass the recently created interceptor inside the decorator.

```
@Controller()
class SomeController {

  @UseInterceptors(OverrideResponseInterceptor)
  async processMessage(...) {
    return 'processed';
  }
}
```

And that's it
You can also watch  youtube video on interceptors where I gave the detailed Explanation of Interceptors https://youtu.be/v5zvWQagcO0

**Extra Tip**

Instead of using env variables as process.env.NODE_ENV I would recommend you to use
@nestjs/config package which gives extra abstraction over the env variables.
If you are interested you can watch the following video https://youtu.be/7OJE4wwZ0R0
You can also read the documentation on env variables at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration